# Calculate end rotation drawing circles

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I have one circle, which grows and shrinks by manipulating the radius in a loop. 
While growing and shrinking, I draw a point on that circle. And within the same loop, increasing the angle for a next point.

*originally it's written in JS, but I guess the math /theory will be the same*

The setup is like this:

- radius = 0;
- circleAngle = 0;
- radiusAngle = 0;
- speed = 0.02;
- radiusSpeed = 4;
- circleSpeed = 2;

Within the loop, I update the angle for both the circle and the drawing line:

```
radius = Math.cos(radiusAngle) * 100;

// creating new point for line  
let pointOnCircle = {
    x: Math.cos(circleAngle) * radius,
    y: Math.sin(circleAngle) * radius
};

circleAngle += speed * circleSpeed;
radiusAngle += speed * radiusSpeed;
```

Within this same loop, I draw the circle with `radius` as the radius. And draw a point with x and y position of `pointOnCircle.x` and `pointOnCircle.y`

Now, after unknown times of rotation, the drawing line is back to where it started, closing the path perfectly. And depending on the settings, some type of pattern / flower thing is drawn. This unknown times of rotations is what I want to calculate.

A working example can be found here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RGKOjP

While playing with the variables `radiusSpeed` and `circleSpeed` I logged the angles and checked when the line was back at the beginning again.

The results are as following. Where the first number is the variable `radiusSpeed`, the second is `circleSpeed`. The results are `radiusAngle` and `circleAngle` in degrees, at the moment the line comes back to its beginning:

- 1, 1: 180, 180
- 1, 2: 360, 720
- 1, 3: 180, 540
- 1, 4: 360, 1440
- 1, 5: 180, 900
- 2, 1: 720, 360
- 2, 2: 180, 180
- 2, 3: 720, 1080
- 2, 4: 360, 720
- 2, 5: 720, 1800
- 3, 1: 540, 180
- 3, 2: 1080, 720
- 3, 3: 180, 180
- 3, 4: 1080, 1440
- 3, 5: 540, 900

I would like to calculate the rotations needed for the line to come back at the beginning and closing the path. 
There clearly is a pattern in the outcome. But I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve got a curve given in polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$, where $r$ and $\theta$ are both periodic functions of some parameter $t$. To reduce clutter, let’s take the maximum radius to be $1$ instead of $100$, since that’s not going to change when or how often the curve returns to its starting point, which will then be $r=1$ and $\theta=0$.

The polar angle $\theta$ is just swept out at a constant rate: $$\theta(t)=\omega_1t\tag{1}$$ where $\omega_1=$`speed * circleSpeed`. We also have the `radiusAngle` being swept out at a (possibly different) constant rate: $\phi(t)=\omega_2t$, with $\omega_2=$`speed * radiusSpeed`. The radius thus varies sinusoidally: $$r=\cos{\phi(t)}=\cos{\omega_2t}.\tag{2}$$ Eliminating $t$ from these equations gives $$r=\cos{{\omega_2\over\omega_1}\theta}.\tag{3}$$

For this to represent the same point as the starting point, we must have $\theta=2n\pi$ ($n\in\mathbb Z$) and $r=1$, or, since $r$ can be negative, $\theta=(2n+1)\pi$ and $r=-1$. Plugging the first condition into (3), we get $$\cos\left({2{\omega_2\over\omega_1}n\pi}\right)=1 \\ 2{\omega_2\over\omega_1}n\pi = 2m\pi \\ {\omega_2\over\omega_1}n = m$$ for some integers $m$ and $n$. This can only hold if the ratio $\omega_2/\omega_1=$`radiusSpeed / circleSpeed` is rational, which it is in all of the cases that you tried. If we express this ratio in lowest terms as $p/q$, we get $pn=qm$, so we can find the smallest positive $n$ and $m$ for which this holds by computing the LCM of $p$ and $q$.

Turning to the second possibility, $$\cos{\left({\omega_2\over\omega_1}(2n+1)\pi\right)}=-1 \\ {\omega_2\over\omega_1}(2n+1)\pi=(2m+1)\pi \\ {\omega_2\over\omega_1}(2n+1)=2m+1.$$ As before, we can rewrite this as $p(2n+1)=q(2m+1)$, which is similar to the previous equation except that both factors have to be odd.

So, to find the recurrence angles $\theta$ and $\phi$, start by expressing `radiusSpeed / circleSpeed` in lowest terms as $p/q$ and find the LCM of the numerator and denominator. Divide this number by $p$ and $q$, respectively, to get the values $a$ and $b$. If these two numbers are both odd, then $\theta=\pi a$ and $\phi=\pi b$, otherwise $\theta=2\pi a$ and $\phi=2\pi b$.

As a sanity check on this formula, we can see that it is consistent with some of the patterns in your data: the results are symmetric, in that swapping the two speeds also swaps the angles; all of the cases in which the two speeds are equal have the same angles; and cases 1,2 and 2,4 also have the same angles.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive explanation. The solution was harder than I thought but it really helped. One question: if a = LCM / p and b = LCM / q, isn't it the same as a = q and b = p?

Comment: @Pimmol Good catch! Yes, since $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, then LCM = $pq$. That simplifies things a bit.

Comment: Great, i appriciate your effort. I didn't know the reason, I just saw it in the output :). thanks!